# how to use "findby" doctrine with input as array?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

Could anyone tell me how to use 'findby' with input as an array of objects??
i got code like this:

```
public function getIpOnline($acc)
{
    try {                    
        $rs = $this->em
            ->getRepository($this->target)
            ->findBy(array('login' => $acc))
        ;
    } catch (Exception $e) {          
        echo "ERROR ".$this->target." DAO: ".$e;
    }               
    var_dump($rs);exit();
    return $rs;     
}
```

and i got error :

```
 Catchable fatal error: Object of class Character could not be converted to string in /var/www/xxx.com/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php on line 67
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`$this->target` is probably an object but you must returns the name of the class of an object.

Have you try to use `get_class`?

Or more simply `Character::class` :)

Like you asked, this is your example with `get_class`:

```
public function getIpOnline($acc)
{
    $nameClass = get_class($this->target);

    try {
        $rs = $this->em
            ->getRepository($nameClass)
            ->findBy(['login' => $acc]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'ERROR ' . $nameClass . ' DAO: ' . $e;
    }
    die(var_dump($rs));

    return $rs;
}
```

Comment: could u please tell me in detail?? i don't understand.

Comment: @Hanata In function getRepository($repoName); you have to pass class name of Entity. for example you can type there 'Product\Entity\Phone', or use function get_class($object), or just use Product::class. All these soultions will return full class name with namespace of class/object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only in case when your instance `$name` have magic method `__toString`.

Fox example:

```
class Name
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return 'ipad';
    }
}

$name = new Name();
$product = $entityManager->getRepository('Product')->findBy(['name' => $name]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getIpOnline($acc)
{
 try {                    
    $rs = $this->em->getRepository($this->target)-findBy(['login' => $acc));

 /* or u can also use findOneBy if expecting result is a single record and find corresponding data only based in $acc
  $rs = $this->em->getRepository($this->target)-findOneByLogin($acc);
 */

 } catch (Exception $e) {          
    echo "ERROR ".$this->target." DAO: ".$e;
}               
var_dump($rs);exit();
return $rs;
```

}

also see http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database